# Refactor using COALESCE, ISNULL or CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, refactoring

I have this following sql query

```
GO
SELECT @StartDate= table1.StartDate, @EndDate= table2.EndDate from table1 join table2

SELECT @StartDate= table2.StartDate, @EndDate= table3.EndDate from table2 join table3

SELECT @StartDate= table3.StartDate, @EndDate= table4.EndDate from table3 join table4
```

Basically, if the last query is not null then that would be the final value of the `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. What is the best approach on this, I am thinking of using `ISNULL`, `COALESCE` or `CASE` `WHEN`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no need for 3 queries to get the desired result. `ISNULL` function is evaluated only once. `COALESCE` expression can be evaluated multiple times.

```
  SELECT @StartDate = COALESCE(table3.StartDate, table2.StartDate, table1.StartDate)
        ,@EndDate = COALESCE(table4.EndDate, table3.EndDate, table2.EndDate)
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
    LEFT JOIN table3
    LEFT JOIN table4
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what OP means by "the last query is not null".  Would there be a record in table4 in this case?  If not, I'd suggest modifying this solution to use LEFT JOIN rather than INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [RecordID] TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
);

DECLARE @DataSourceDates01 TABLE
(
    [RecordID] TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
   ,[StartDate] DATETIME2
   ,[EndDate] DATETIME2
);

DECLARE @DataSourceDates02 TABLE
(
    [RecordID] TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
   ,[StartDate] DATETIME2
   ,[EndDate] DATETIME2
);


DECLARE @DataSourceDates03 TABLE
(
    [RecordID] TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
   ,[StartDate] DATETIME2
   ,[EndDate] DATETIME2
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([RecordID])
VALUES (1), (2), (3);

INSERT INTO @DataSourceDates01 ([RecordID], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES (1, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE());

INSERT INTO @DataSourceDates02 ([RecordID], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES (1, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE())
      ,(2, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE());

INSERT INTO @DataSourceDates03 ([RecordID], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES (1, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE())
      ,(2, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE())
      ,(3, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE());

SELECT DS.[RecordID]
      ,COALESCE(DS1.[StartDate], DS2.[StartDate], DS3.[StartDate]) AS [StartDate]
      ,COALESCE(DS1.[EndDate], DS2.[EndDate], DS3.[EndDate]) AS [EndDate]
FROM @DataSource DS
LEFT JOIN @DataSourceDates01 DS1
    ON DS.[RecordID] = DS1.[RecordID]
LEFT JOIN @DataSourceDates02 DS2
    ON DS.[RecordID] = DS2.[RecordID]
LEFT JOIN @DataSourceDates03 DS3
    ON DS.[RecordID] = DS3.[RecordID];
```